# scp multiple files with single command

Tags: ssh, scp, sftp

I have seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886179/scp-or-sftp-copy-multiple-files-with-single-command

But for some reason it does not work for me.

If I run:

```
scp me@remote:/path/to/files/{a,b} ./
```

I get asked for the password for each file. If I try the suggestions from the quoted question above:

```
scp me@remote:/path/to/file/\{a,b\} ./
```

I get

```
scp: /path/to/file/{a,b}: No such file or directory
```

And

```
scp me@remote:/path/to/file/"a b" ./
```

I get

```
scp: /path/to/file/a b: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? I make sure to not have spaces between the commas, and I have tried all the variations on the answers from the question above.

The files are there, I can get them with the first command, but it asks for a password for every file.

Comment: Look [how crazy `scp` is](https://superuser.com/a/1634882/432690). Or used to be, see the "preliminary note" there. The method with `me@remote:/path/to/file/\{a,b\}` relies on two things: the craziness of `scp` and the ability of your remote shell to expand `/path/to/file/{a,b}`. Hence the questions: (1) is your `scp` the legacy (crazy) `scp`? (2) Can your shell on the remote side expand these braces? What if you expand them instead? `scp me@remote:'"/path/to/files/a" "/path/to/files/b"' ./`. [You may need to use `-T`.](https://superuser.com/a/1685833/432690).

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0) `-O` brings back the craziness. :) Not that I advise this. I think you can make your first command "remember" your password if you follow [this answer that uses `ControlMaster`](https://superuser.com/a/1727337/432690).

Comment: or you can use `ssh-agent` to cache your private key(s) for a configurable period of time, assuming you're using key-based auth rather than password auth (which is what you *should* be using).   if you haven't already generated a key pair, run `ssh-keygen`. copy your public key to the remote host with `ssh-copy-id remotehost`. run `ssh-agent`. Now you will be able to `scp` as often as you like, you won't be asked for the password again until the time-to-live expires. **read and understand the man pages for all of these commands before running any of them.**